# Is there a way to disable global Windows hotkeys?

Tags: windows, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, productivity

Basically I set up some global hotkeys for my app such as WinKey+Home/End/-/+, and Function keys, but Windows steals the WinKey+Home/End/+ hotkeys and doesn't let me app to fire its own actions.

I can see what Windows is doing with these global hotkeys but is there a way to disable these? They are not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto Hotkey to reassign keys to your personal choice.

For some Apps you will need to re-assign the Windows key to something different before installing your App.

Otherwise you cannot natively and globally disable Windows Hot Keys.

I have found through many years of experience that it is normally better to have Windows have its hot keys (many people use them) and assign other keys to other Apps.

Another approach is the use a different Hot Key for your App. I do this for SnagIt, VMware and other Apps I have and these do not interfere with Windows chosen Hot Keys.

However you can change them as you need to as described initially.

Comment: Thanks but if I do that my global hotkeys for my app will work? If I am not wrong AH will remap these regardless. Right now my app and Windows is using the same hotkeys so Windows steals the hotkeys before my app can do anything about it.

Comment: You would need to change the Windows hot key to something different with Auto Hot Key to let your App use that key.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I just dont see how the remap key will trigger the action in my app though because for example Win key + Home will now be Ctrl+Insert, and no other will be able to receive the Win key combo. My app is also using the global hotkey that's the issue.

Comment: Try it. Your app may have some issues based on what you have written. Can you use a different key for your App.  I use different hot keys for SnagIt, VMware, and other Apps using Hot Keys and these do not interfere with Windows.